# C# Method that automates sending commands every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, methods

I have 6 devices connected to a converter RS485/USB. 
When sending ID0# command: (0# = 01 or 02 or 03 or 04 or 05 or 06)
receive a string `IDXX  0#,22008,21930,00000, n / a, n / a` ! 
Then the string is divided with substring() and the fragments go to variables.
As should be the method which automates sending commands every 10 seconds, receive the strings, splits with substring() and stores them in variables?

I try like this:
linked with a tick on timer1 with interval 10000.

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s_ID = stringOut.Trim().Substring(1,2);
        string ID01 = "id01";
        string id01_02mm = "";
        string id01_07mm = "";
        string id01_10mm = "";
        CommPort com = CommPort.Instance;
        ID01 = ConvertEscapeSequences(ID01);
        com.Send(ID01);            

        if(s_ID=="01")
        {
           string id01_time=DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
           string id01_ID = "ID01";
           id01_02mm=stringOut.Trim().Substring(4,5);
           id01_07mm=stringOut.Trim().Substring(10,5);
           id01_10mm=stringOut.Trim().Substring(16,5);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
ocaccy

Comment: What is your question?  What seems to be the problem with the approach you tried?

Comment: What I meant was that I have this code.
However I think it is very simple and can be improved by using OOP, 
because they are 6 devices and in the example I'm using only one!

Comment: What I meant was that I have this code.
However I think it is very simple and can be improved by using OOP, 
because they are 6 devices and in the example I'm using only one!
And in a few minutes I will ask how to launch these values ​​in array with 310 rows and 120 columns.example
 I'm using only one! 

Thanks, mellamokb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to organize your code a little more around OOP, maybe create a `RS485USBDevice` class that does the parsing and sending.  Then you create and command 6 instances.  It might look something like the following:

```
public class RS485USBDevice
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Id_02mm { get; set; } // need more descriptive name
    public string Id_07mm { get; set; } // need more descriptive name
    public string Id_10mm { get; set; } // need more descriptive name
    public DateTime LastRequestTime { get; set; }

    public RS485USBDevice(int deviceId)
    {
        this.DeviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public void SendRequest()
    {
        // where does CommPort come from? custom class?
        CommPort com = CommPort.Instance;
        string ID = "id0" + this.DeviceId;
        ID = ConvertEscapeSequences(ID);
        com.Send(ID);  // shouldn't this have a return value

        // where does stringOut come from? naughty global variable
        this.Id_02mm = stringOut.Trim().Substring(4,5);
        this.Id_07mm = stringOut.Trim().Substring(10,5);
        this.Id_10mm = stringOut.Trim().Substring(16,5);
        this.LastRequestTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    private List<RS485USBDevice> _devices;

    public MainClass()
    {
        // initialize setup of all 6 devices
        this._devices = new List<RS485USBDevice>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            var device = new RS485USBDevice(i);
            this._devices.Add(device);
        }
    }

    // this should be timer tick event on 10 seconds
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make all devices send
        foreach (var device in this._devices)
            device.SendRequest();

        // do something with response data from device obj
    }
}
```

Comment: My friend mellamokb, how to give you a hug?
It's pretty good, won a fan!
We sincerely thank you.